# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error after using Cloudflare

Tags: google-chrome, drupal, dns, cloudflare

After I started using Cloudflare I started facing this error in my website(frequently in chrome and opera).

[image]

Some of the points I have found out after testing multiple times are:

1. So far I have faced this problem in Google Chrome, Chromium, and Opera. Chrome being the major one for my visitors.
2. The inner pages are working fine. For example `example.com/about-us` is working fine but the error occurs when we visit `example.com` .
3. I once thought this is because of too many links in my home page. So tried removing all the links on home page but the error continued.
4. If I type `example.com/node` instead of `example.com` it works fine(`example.com/node` being the default home page of drupal website). But users generally type `example.com` so it can't be the solution.

In cloudflare settings I have changed the SSL mode to "Full Strict" from "Flexible" as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143193/cloudflare-and-nginx-too-many-redirects) answer. It's been more than 10 hours but it hasn't helped so far.

I am using Godaddy's linux hosting. It's a Drupal Website.

Any clue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SSL the issue most likely is due to the fact that you have some redirects on your website ( .htaccess ) to the httpS version of the site . On top of that Cloudflare have features in their Crypto section that allow you to make redirects directly from there. Thus if you have set such rules both places, you will most likely get a redirect looop.

My advice would be for you to check the Crypto section of your CloudFlare account and make sure that

**Automatic HTTPS Rewrites**
and
**HTTP Strict Transport Security**

are disabled.

Then clear the Cloudflare cache and try accessing your website from a fresh browser.

This should do the trick, if not , you should provide us with your .htaccess content so that the case can be resolved.

Comment: Automatic HTTPS Rewrites and HTTP Strict Transport Security are already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

**Try setting SSL/TLS -> Overview from Flexible to Full**

This happens to me a lot after migrating domains from Google Domains or Namecheap, especially if I turned on "Always Use HTTPS."

As I understand, it has to do with your browser getting confused that your origin server behind Cloudfare has a slightly different SSL Configuration than Cloudflare itself, which is now handling DNS.

When you configure SSL/TLS to Full in the Cloudflare Dashboard, that basically tells Cloudflare to fully handle SSL for the Origin Server and ignore the Origin Server's certificate.

If you still need the SSL from your Origin Server, this may not be an ideal solution, or you may need to create a special Cloudflare Rule for your certificate to pass through under certain conditions.

Official Docs

https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/troubleshooting/too-many-redirects/#encryption-mode-misconfigurations